# Javascript associative array values

Tags: javascript, associative-array

Can someone help me with this:
I ahev the following array

```
   var dados= {"idCodigo":"593392","nome_localidade":"Vila Praia de \u00c2ncora","morada":"Rua dos   Pescadores","nome_concelho":"XXXX"};
```

And i want to access values of it using

```
console.log(dados);
           console.log(dados["idCodigo"]);
```

But it says undefined in the second console.log

Any help?

Thanks

All code

```
<script>
$(document).on("change", '#edit_cod', function (e) {
    var morada = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../db/getFromDatabase.php',
        data: {getMorada: morada},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (resposta) {
           var dados =  resposta;
           console.log(dados);
           console.log(dados["idCodigo"]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work for me.

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: "_But it says undefined in the second console.log_" can you please show us where you are getting that result?

Comment: This code looks perfectly valid.

Comment: Amy, the OP says that's it's an associative array which is another way of saying it's an object - it's just not a term generally used by JS devs that's all.

Comment: Please take a look at this repl.

Literally copied and pasted your issue. There is nothing wrong with your code. 
https://repl.it/repls/GoodnaturedEvenClingfish

Comment: Okay you just updated your questions which means your problem looks like its javascript scope related. The associative array (object) is not defined in the second code snippet

Comment: What are you getting for `console.log(typeof dados);` inside ajax success method?

Comment: `dataType: 'html',` is wrong if you're expecting JSON.

Comment: @andy you should submit that as an answer so you win some internet points.  nice catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're asking the server for a HTML response rather than JSON. Note that using `dataType: 'json'` as part of a jQuery AJAX call will mean that the JSON is automatically parsed by the library so you don't have to do it. With that in mind perhaps try this instead.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '../db/getFromDatabase.php',
  data: {getMorada: morada},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (dados) {
    console.log(dados);
    console.log(dados["idCodigo"]);
  }
});
```